# Issue with Debugging Multiple Projects Simultaneously in Visual Studio on Windows 11

Tags: visual-studio

I've encountered a problem in Visual Studio where I can run any of my projects individually without any issues, but when I attempt to debug multiple projects simultaneously, I receive an error. This behavior started after I upgraded to Windows 11.

The error message states:

"Unable to start debugging. Make sure the startup project is set correctly. You can change the startup project by selecting the 'Set as Startup Project' command from the right-click menu in Solution Explorer."

[image]

Despite setting a specific project as the startup project and confirming that it works when launched alone, the error persists when I select the same project within a multiple startup configuration. The issue does not occur when the projects are run individually.

Here is what I have tried so far:

Ensuring that the startup project is correctly set.
Checking for port conflicts between projects.
Verifying project dependencies and build configurations.
Running Visual Studio as an administrator.
The problem seems to be specific to running in a multi-project startup environment, as individual project execution works flawlessly. I suspect it might be related to some nuances introduced with Windows 11 because on my previous computer on Windows 10 it was OK.

Before :
[image]

After :
[image]

Has anyone faced a similar issue or can suggest further troubleshooting steps for this multi-project debugging problem in Visual Studio on Windows 11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue corrected in Visual Studio version 17.9.2:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Multiple-Startup-Projects-Not-Saving-Con/10585328